# New to programming, JDK bundled with Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1?

Tags: java, macos, android-studio

I'm new to programming and wanted to give the newest Android Studio a try on OSX as I'm getting started.

I went to:

https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/canary/latest/

where it said:

> Please download a full IDE image linked below to ensure you have the
>   correct JDK bundled with the installation.

I downloaded the file and completed the install and now get a warning in Android Studio to:

> Please choose a valid JDK directory.

There is a jdk subfolder in the Package Contents of the Android Studio program itself at:

> Applications/Android Studio/Contents/jre/jdk

However, this doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I know you can download Java from Oracle's website, but I'm not sure if this is what I should be doing or not.

At first I thought the text from the install page linked above meant that the JDK was bundled in the Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 installer, but now I'm thinking that is not the case.

If I do need to get a JDK for my Mac, which one do I use please? Otherwise, if a JDK came with Android Studio, how do I select the valid JDK directory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it really `/jre/jdk`? There is often a JRE inside the JDK and I think you would take the outter (jdk) folder as target.

Comment: Yes, just double checked and the path is as I have written above. Just installing the latest JDK got me up and running though.

Comment: Just downloaded the zip & it's indeed an odd layout. The directory that should be working is `Applications/Android Studio/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/` - they have more odd subdirectories in there. It's not worth bothering if you already downloaded a jdk-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android tools install the SDK for Android, but you still need a JDK. Install this one for mac osx:

jdk-8u91-macosx-x64.dmg

on page:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: @JETkoten Glad to hear it!